# Backbone collection parse never fires, collection.models should have 2 items but is 0

Tags: backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

Here is my MemberView.js ...

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/MembersCollection',
    'text!templates/memTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, MembersCollection, memTemplate) {

    var MembersView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#page"),

        initialize: function() {
            var that = this;
            this.collection = new MembersCollection([]); 
            this.collection.fetch({ 
                success : function(collection, response, options) {
                    that.render();
                }, 
                error: function(collection, response, options) {
                    console.log('members fetch error: '+response.responseText);
                    alert(response.responseText);
                } 
            });
        },

        render: function() {
            var data = { members : this.collection.models };
            var compiledTemplate = _.template( memTemplate, data );
            this.$el.html( compiledTemplate ); 
        }

    });

    return MembersView;

});
```

Here is my MemberCollection.js ...

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/Member'
], function($, _, Backbone, Member) {

var MembersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Member,

    initialize : function(models, options) { },

    url : '/modular-backbone/server/member',

    parse: function (response) {
        console.log("In Parse=" + response.length);
        return response;
    }
  });

  return MembersCollection;

});
```

There is never a "In Parse=?" in the console so I have to assume collection.parse is not fireing. Also, if I put a break in the view.render method, collection.models is always a zero length array even though I can clearly see 2 Member records in the fetch success response. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot for your advice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable...

I went back and cleaned up a bunch of commented out lines in a few js files, ran the app again and now it's working perfectly. This makes no sense at all.